# Why is the list not altering after operations performed in a function?

Tags: python, list, function

```
def test(nums):
    nums = list(set(nums))

nums = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
test(nums)
print(nums)
```

`[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]`

I am not able to understand the process. If I do something like

```
def test(nums):
    nums.append(7)

nums = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
test(nums)
print(nums)
```

`[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,7]`

the list alters.

Comment: It’s a case of *assignment* (into the local scope) vs *mutating* the original object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything is object in python
when you are using object method inside any function then python changes that object depending upon that method. `append` is inplace in your case

In this case,

```
def test(nums):
    nums.append(7)

nums = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
test(nums)
print(nums)
```

`nums` is list object, and you are calling `append` method on that list object which is inplace so it is changing the original list.

While in this case,

```
def test(nums):
    nums = list(set(nums))

nums = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
test(nums)
print(nums)
```

you have passed your list object to your function, but `nums = list(set(nums))` in this line, you assigned a new list object to `nums` and previous `nums` is lost.

for clarification you can print the id of these objects,

```
def test(nums):
    print(id(nums)) # this will be original list id
    nums = list(set(nums))
    print(id(nums)) # this will be changed

nums = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
print(id(nums)) # this will be original list id
test(nums)
print(id(nums)) # this will be original list id
print(nums)
```

and for other case,

```
def test(nums):
    print(id(nums)) # this will be original list id
    nums.append(7)
    print(id(nums)) # this will be original list id

nums = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
print(id(nums)) # this will be original list id
test(nums)
print(id(nums)) # this will be original list id
print(nums)
```

If you do

```
def test(nums):
  print(id(nums)) # this will be original list id
  nums[:] = [1,2,3]
  print(id(nums)) # this will be original list id


nums = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
print(id(nums)) # this will be original list id
test(nums)
print(id(nums)) # this will be original list id
print(nums)
```

In this case, also when you do slicing then `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` dunder methods are used, which change the list object inplace.